# bowed string (e.g. violin) synthesis algorithm

Tags: algorithm, audio, sound-synthesis

Is there a well known algorithm for synthesising bowed string instruments (e.g. violins)?

I know for plucked strings (e.g. guitars) there's the karplus-strong algorithm, which I have succesfully implemented in the past.

Ideally I would like an algorithm describing a computer program for generating/synthesizing the digital signal.

For example, the karplus-strong algorithm can be summerized as follows:

- Determine the period length of the frequency you want to synthesize and create a buffer of exactly that size
- Fill the buffer with random numbers (white noise)
- Iterate over the buffer, each time average each poitn with the next point then outputting it to the output stream.
- Repeat for the desired amount of time while applying some damping

I wonder if something similar exists for bowed strings.

Footnote:

Now, I know nothing about the physics of how strings produce the sound, so I have no idea how one would derive such an algorithm. For the karplus-strong algorithm, I simply read it in the original paper and applied it "blindly". I would have never guessed that starting with a while noise and continuously damping it would produce a sound so similar to a plucked string.

**EDIT**:

As usual, the close parade has started.

**Before voting to close this question, please consider the following:**

- This question is not about physics. It's not about the mechanics of the string vibration or interaction with the bow and air to produce the sound.
- This question is about the existence of a specific well known algorithm to synthesize the sound. It's strictly a question about programming.

Comment: You might have better luck with this question at https://physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RBarryYoung It's not a question about physics. It's a question about how to program the thing. Not about the string/air/wave mechanism that produce the sound.

Comment: obtain samples, do oscilograms and spectrograms ... fit/parametrize with polynomial or goinometric ... a lot of research and data compiling to do ...

Comment: "*the karplus-strong algorithm ... I wonder if something similar exists for bowed strings*".  This is a question that folks at https://phyiscs.stackexchange.com are more likely to know.  They also have more folks there with experience in turning ODEs and PDEs into numerical and simulation programs.  And for the record, I did not vote to close your question.  If you want it here, I am fine with it, I was just trying to point out that there are a lot more numerical and simulation programmers over there.

Answer (score 3):

Weirdly i was able to find some stuff on this on the [Stanford](https://chuck.stanford.edu/doc/) chuck website.

The code is written in a language called ChucK which is apparently specific for audio programming. You will have to run to use this code snippet. But here is its implementation in chuck:

```
// patch
Bowed bow => dac;

// scale
[0, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11] @=> int scale[];

// infinite time loop
while( true )
{
    // set
    Math.random2f( 0, 1 ) => bow.bowPressure;
    Math.random2f( 0, 1 ) => bow.bowPosition;
    Math.random2f( 0, 12 ) => bow.vibratoFreq;
    Math.random2f( 0, 1 ) => bow.vibratoGain;
    Math.random2f( 0, 1 ) => bow.volume;

    // print
    <<< "---", "" >>>;
    <<< "bow pressure:", bow.bowPressure() >>>;
    <<< "bow position:", bow.bowPosition() >>>;
    <<< "vibrato freq:", bow.vibratoFreq() >>>;
    <<< "vibrato gain:", bow.vibratoGain() >>>;
    <<< "volume:", bow.volume() >>>;

    // set freq
    scale[Math.random2(0,scale.size()-1)] + 57 => Std.mtof => bow.freq;
    // go
    .8 => bow.noteOn;

    // advance time
    Math.random2f(.8, 2)::second => now;
}
```

Edit: The above is just the implementation, the source file for it is [here.](http://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/Bowed_8h_source.html)

Comment: Interesting find. This seems to just be the usage code. The actual implementation might be this. https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/Bowed_8h_source.html looking further into it

Comment: Hope you find it useful, ill update the post to reflect the source.

Answer (score 1):

Not an algorithm, but there's an open source library (under a very [liberal license](https://github.com/thestk/stk/blob/master/LICENSE)) that implements synthesis algorithms in C++ for several instruments, including bowed strings.

The Synthesis ToolKit (STK)

Official homepage: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/

Github link: https://github.com/thestk/stk

Files with code relevant to synthesis of bowed string instruments:

- [include/Bowed.h](https://github.com/thestk/stk/blob/master/include/Bowed.h)
- [src/Bowed.cpp](https://github.com/thestk/stk/blob/master/src/Bowed.cpp)
- [include/BowTable.h](https://github.com/thestk/stk/blob/master/include/BowTable.h)

The comments in the code make references to two papers:

- [Efficient Simulation of the Reed-Bore and Bow-String Mechanisms](http://hdl.handle.net/2027/spo.bbp2372.1986.054)
   by Julius Smith (1986) ([PDF](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/p/pod/dod-idx/efficient-simulation-of-the-reed-bore-and-bow-string.pdf?c=icmc;idno=bbp2372.1986.054;format=pdf))
- [On the Fundamentals of Bowed String Dynamics](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/247040060_On_the_fundamentals_of_bowed_string_dynamics) by Michael McIntyre & Jim Woodhouse (1979) ([PDF](http://www2.eng.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejw12/JW%20PDFs/Fundamentals.pdf))

Julius Smith also has information about bowed string synthesis available on his (standford) website:

[Bowed Strings section of the "Physical Audio Signal Processing" book](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/pasp/Bowed_Strings.html)

[MUS420 Lecture
Digital Waveguide Modeling of Bowed Strings](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/BowedStrings/)